# The distribution of a random variable X

Tags: probability

The distribution of a random variable X, whose range
is {−a, 0, a}, is given by
P{X = −a} = p1, P{X = a} = p2
Given that X has mean 0 and variance 1, work out the values of p1, p2 in terms of a.

can someone help me???

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E[X]=-ap_1+ap_2=0$ and use that and $E[X^2]-E[X]=1$ to compute $p_1$ or $p_2$